# How do I get a string that's the text() of an element, but with spaces added after divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/annablabber/pbwc8jvu/11/)

Hi! I'm trying to output a string from the .contents().text() of an element... but with **spaces between the content of each div** (without changing the actual DOM).

**HTML:**

```
<!-- I don't have control over how many divs are in .myTextArea, or what text. It's really dynamic. There are also lists, etc.--tons of different types of elements. -->

<div class="myTextArea">

  <div>Hey there!</div><div>I like turtles.</div><div>Do you like them?</div>

</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var myTextDescription = $(".myTextArea").contents().text();

console.log(myTextDescription);
```

Currently, it outputs:

```
Hey there!I like turtles.Do you like them?
```

...and this is what I want it to output: The same thing, but with **spaces** after the content of each div:

```
Hey there! I like turtles. Do you like them?
```

---

Note: Other answers on SO make you change the actual DOM (AKA, they add actual spaces after the elements on the page), and then they just grab the text() string. I don't want to change the DOM.

Also, I can't use .html() instead and try to strip away stuff, because there will be *wayyyyyy* too many types of elements to worry about.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/annablabber/pbwc8jvu/11/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Replace `.text()` with:

```
//get text content of all nodes
.map((i,d) => d.textContent).get()
//remove white space
.filter(t => !!t.trim())
//join the text from all nodes with a space
.join(' ');
```

Check out the demo below:

```js
var myTextDescription = $(".myTextArea").contents().map((i,d) => d.textContent).get().filter(t => !!t.trim()).join(' ');

console.log(myTextDescription);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myTextArea">

  <div>Hey there!</div><div>I like turtles.</div><div>Do you like them?</div>

</div>
```

In case you needed to exclude text in a div, say with a class `exclude` you can use the `:not()` psedo selector like so:

```
... .contents(':not(".exclude")') ....
```

..as in the demo below:

```js
var myTextDescription = $(".myTextArea").contents(':not(".exclude")').map((i,d) => d.textContent).get().filter(t => !!t.trim()).join(' ');

console.log(myTextDescription);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myTextArea">

  <div>Hey there!</div><div class="exclude">Please exclude this!</div><div>I like turtles.</div><div>Do you like them?</div><div class="exclude">Please exclude this too!</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to exclude text from divs with certain classes (".do-not-include")? I tried ".not('.do-not-include')" but it seems to be not working. I can also ask this in another SO question as well if needed.

Comment: amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use JavaScript's querySelectorAll method to return a list of all the DIVs in your myTextArea element. You can then run through each element in the list, get its innerText and place a space after each one:

```js
var myTexts = document.querySelectorAll('.myTextArea > div');
var show = document.querySelector('#show');
var output = "";

for (var x = 0; x < myTexts.length; x++) {
  if (output == "") { // Skip adding space before first string
    output = myTexts[x].innerText;
  } else { // Add space before each appended string
    output += " " + myTexts[x].innerText;
  }
}

show.innerText = output;
```

```html
<div class="myTextArea">
  <div>Hey there!</div>
  <div>I like turtles.</div>
  <div>Do you like them?</div>

</div>

<div id="show"></div>
```